# Box-API getting and HTTP 411 on Update Folder

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to perform an "Update Folder" using Box API v2.0

The point is that i'm receiving the following answer directly from the HTTP PUT

```
<html>
<head><title>411 Length Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>411 Length Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the docs: http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-update-information-about-a-folder, there is no need to send any Content-Length in the request, just the Authorization header.

Has anyone gone through this? Is it possible that nginx is rejecting the request before reaching box api?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code that you're using to generate the HTTP request, or if possible a trace of the request as it's going over the wire.

Comment: John, for some reason, the request body was not being sent. Now i made sure the at least the new name is in the body, and everything worked as expected. So, bad from my side. Anyway the error was not very "helpful". Thanks.

PD: Since i'm new user, i'll reply my own question in 5 hours when i'm able to and mark is as answered.

Comment: That'll do it. :) Nice work figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the request body was not being sent. Now i made sure the at least the new name is in the body, and everything worked as expected. So, bad from my side. Anyway the error was not very "helpful". Thanks